# Why can't PowerShell find the gcloud cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-powershell

I've updated the Google Cloud SDK (gcloud), both in general with:

```
gcloud components update
```

And just for PowerShell with:

```
gcloud components update powershell
```

Running `gcloud --version` shows:

```
Google Cloud SDK 122.0.0
beta 2016.01.12
bq 2.0.24
bq-win 2.0.24
bundled-python 2.7.10
core 2016.08.16
core-win 2016.08.05
gcloud
gsutil 4.20
gsutil-win 4.20
powershell 0.1.3
windows-ssh-tools 2016.05.13
```

When I open PowerShell and try `Get-GcsBucket` though, I see this error:

> Get-GcsBucket : The term 'Get-GcsBucket' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

How can I get PowerShell to recognize the gcloud cmdlets?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The simplest fix for most people will be to uninstall and reinstall the Google Cloud SDK. This doesn't lose any configuration information, so you don't need to run `gcloud init` or `gcloud auth` afterwards.

As an alternative, you can run the command that the installer would normally run. Find your Google Cloud SDK installation directory (e.g. `%AppData%\..\Local\Google\Cloud SDK` or `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Cloud SDK`). Within that directory, find `google-cloud-sdk\platform\GoogleCloudPowerShell`. In there, there's a script called `AppendPsModulePath.ps1`. Run that, and it will modify the `PSModulePath` environment variable for your current user. From then on, new PowerShell windows will have the cmdlets available.

Comment: Seems like first link(`PSModulePath`) is no longer available!.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM: Mmm... sorry about that. I'll remove the first paragraph. Although I'd also note that the PowerShell cmdlets are basically deprecated at this stage. (I don't know if they're even still shipping.)